# In VSCode, how do I turn off code fragment for "for" loop and "if"

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the newest version of VSCode (1.0), I find the code fragment for 'for' and 'if' is added. They are automatically inserted to my code when I type "for" then "(". The completion is not what I want. How do I turn them off?

Comment: Which programming language? Please provide a small code sample that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean, that you don't want the auto closing bracket functionality.

Code -> Preferences -> Workspace Settings

Write add to your settings.json

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false
```

As Wosi pointed out, more information would help to give you a better answer.